# I am using a new Font in Python Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, fonts

I have installed a new font on my computer and have installed it on my computer as well.
Now i am using it in my Python code using the tkinter Library but its not working.

```
    self.master = master
    self.my_font = tkinter.font.Font(self.master, family="My Girl Is Retro Regular")
    self.master.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=2)
    self.master.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    self.playPhoto = PhotoImage(file='toppic.png')
    self.toppic = Label(self.master,image=self.playPhoto)
    self.toppic.grid(pady=(0,50))
    self.youtubeLinkLabel = Label(self.master, text="Paste the YouTube Link Below: ", font=("My Girl Is Retro Regular", 30),fg='red')
    self.youtubeLinkLabel.grid(pady=(0,20))
    self.youtubeEntryVar = StringVar()
    self.youtubeEntry = Entry(self.master, width=70, textvariable=self.youtubeEntryVar,font=("Agency FB", 25),fg='green')
    self.youtubeEntry.grid(pady=(0, 15),ipady=10)

    self.youtubeEntryError = Label(self.master, text="", font=("Concert One", 20))
    self.youtubeEntryError.grid(pady=(0, 8))

    # Asking where to save file label
    self.youtubeFileLocationLabel = Label(self.master, text="Choose Directory: ",font=("My Girl Is Retro Regular", 60))
    self.youtubeFileLocationLabel.grid()

    self.youtubeFileLocationEntry = Button(self.master, text="Directory", command=self.openDirectory)
    self.youtubeFileLocationEntry.grid(pady=(10, 3))

    # Entry label if user don`t choose directory
    # openDirectory func
    self.fileLocationLabelError = Label(self.master, text="", font=("My Girl Is Retro Regular", 20))
    self.fileLocationLabelError.grid()

    # What to download MP3 or MP4 label
    self.youtubeChooseLabel = Label(self.master, text="Please choose what to download: ",
                                        font=("My Girl Is Retro Regular", 30))
    self.youtubeChooseLabel.grid()
```

I have searched on Google but i can't figure it out

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the font with incorrect name and you will have noticed that its producing unexpected font. If you are on windows, open the `ttf` file, the name will be there. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

In the above screenshot, font name is `Alien League`. You can try replacing `My Girl Is Retro Regular` with `Comic Sans MS`, a builtin Windows font. It will work.
I have found the correct name of the font you are using. Its `My Girl Is Retro`.

Comment: got it...tnx for your time..There is no need to render..once it is installed on your computer..you can use it fine